# JavaPlot: How can I use the fit method of GNUPlot?

Tags: java, gnuplot, trend, javaplot

I have a set of 6 points. Now I want to create a trend line (fifth-degree polynomial). I don't have much experience with GNUPlot, yet, but I found the "fit" method which should do exactly what I want. The problem is that I don't know how to call the method within JavaPlot. Even if it wasn't implemented in JavaPlot it should be possible to use that method somehow, right? The JavaPlot website even states:

> Moreover, is flexible enough to give special parameters to gnuplot, even if the library does not support it (yet).

Does anyone know how I can plot a fitted (trend) line in JavaPlot?

Answer (score 0):

JavaGnuplotHybrid might be a solution. It allows hybrid programming with Java and gnuplot, which means all gnuplot features are supported. You need to learn some bit about gnuplot first though.

For more details:

1. Project page: https://github.com/mleoking/JavaGnuplotHybrid
2. Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaGnuplotHybrid